# Stopping customers from being redirected to beginning of checkout process when using modified ApplePayHook authorizeOrderPayment function?

Tags: salesforce, applepay, applepayjs, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I have been using the ApplePayHook functions to modify the behavior of the Apple Pay checkout process. I have changed the authorizeOrderPayment function to return an ApplePayHookResult if a user tries to submit a billing address outside of the US or Canada. However, even though I am not providing a redirect URL when I create the ApplePayHookResult, customers are being redirected to the beginning of the checkout process. Is there a way to prevent this redirection?

I have tried returning a new ApplePayHookResult with null for the redirect URL. I was expecting that to ideally keep the apple pay popup open, showing the error message. Otherwise I would hope that the Apple Pay popup would close, but the customers would remain on the same page. Instead, the Apple Pay popup closes and users are redirected to the beginning of the checkout process.